# Is there any way to run ModelBuilder HasData only in migration and not in runtime?

Tags: entity-framework-core

In `OnModelCreating` I am using some seed code:

```
builder.Entity<User>().HasData(new[]
{
    UserEntity.GetAnonymous(),
    UserEntity.GetDefault()
});
```

It correctly runs when doing the migration in the PM console.

**Question**

Is there any way to restrict it to run only when doing a migration and not every time in runtime? (I am aware that runtime model is cached, so building runs only one time but still...)

Comment: HasData does not insert data at runtime.

Comment: @AvinKavish thx for your answer

Comment: It does not insert them at runtime, but it holds your entity objects forever.

Comment: I'm on the same train here. I have a large list of entities in some seeds and this generates a huge delay on the app startup time. Like @g.pickardou, I'm also wondering why this has to be validated during runtime and can't be directly avoided by the framework (or have another mechanism that helps us prevent it).